# The $G$-invariant probability measures are weak-*-closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, probability-theory

First some definitions:

Let $X$ be a compact hausdorff space and $C(X, \mathbb{R})$ the banach space of continuous functions with the $\sup$-norm. It’s dual is the space of signed regular borel measures on $X$: $M(X)$, and there is a bijection: $M(X) \rightarrow C(X, \mathbb{R})^*, \mu \mapsto \phi_{\mu}$ where $\phi_{\mu}(f):= \int_X f \ d \mu$. This bijection (actually an isometry) carries the weak-*-topology of $C(X, \mathbb{R})^*$ over to $M(X)$. As far as I understand, this weak-*-topology on $M(X)$ is now characterised as the coarsest topology that, for every $\mu$, makes the map: $f \mapsto \int_Xf \ d \mu$ continuous. Within $M(X)$ there lies the space of probability measures which satisfy $\mu(X)=1, f \geq 0 \Rightarrow \int_X f \ d \mu \geq 0$.

Now I need to show that if there is a countable group $G$ acting continuously on $X$, then the set $M^1(X)^G$ of $G$-invariant probability measures if weak-*-closed.

My solution manual solves the exercise as follows:

Let $\{\mu_n\}_n$ be a sequence of invariant prob. measures converging to $\mu \in M^1(X)$ (we know $M^1(X)$ is closed). In other words:
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f(x) \ d\mu_n(x)= \int_X f(x) \ d \mu(x)
$$
then for all $f\in C(X), g \in G$:
$$
\int_X f(gx) d \mu(x)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f(gx) \ d\mu_n(x)= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_X f(x) \ d\mu_n(x)= \int_X f(x) d \mu(x)
$$

which shows the claim.

My problem with this proof is that they have shown that $M^1(X)^G$ contains all its limit points. But as I remember I can only deduce from this that $M^1(X)^G$ is closed if the topology were first countable. But as far as I know the weak-*-top. generally isn’t. So what’s my oversight?

*Second question:*

But I think I found a proof not relying on sequences (I define $\pi: G \rightarrow \text{GL}(M^1(X))$ to be the „induced representation“ of the group action if that makes sense):
$$
M^1(X)^G= \bigcap_{g \in G}\{\mu \in M^1(X): \pi(g)\mu = \mu\}= \bigcap_{g \in G}p(\{(\mu, \pi(g)\mu): \mu \in M^1(X)\} \cap \{(\mu, \mu): \mu \in M^1(X)\})
$$

Where $p: M^1(X)  \times M^1(X) \rightarrow M^1(X) $ is the projection onto the first component. I think this shows that $M^1(X)^G$ is closed as the intersection of closed sets. $\{(\mu, \pi(g)\mu): \mu \in M^1(X)\} $ is closed by the closed graph theorem $\{(\mu, \mu): \mu \in M^1(X)\}$ because $M^1(X) $ is hausdorff and the projection is closed because $M^1(X)$ is weak-*-compact.

Does this alternative proof work?

Comment: But then you need to show that $\mu(g)$ is continuous for the weak$^\ast$ topology, which essentially boils down to the computation from your solution manual. Just replace sequences by nets, and everything works exactly the same way.